# Поменять местами максимальный по модулю отрицательный элемент и минимальный положительный

Tags: c#

Требуется поменять местами максимальный по модулю отрицательный элемент и минимальный положительный.

*Тестовый массив:*

```
4 5 6 7 12 -3 4 -5 -7 2
```

Первый элемент равен -12 на позиции 4, второй элемент равен 2 на позиции 9.

Результат:

```cs
4 5 6 7 2 -3 4 5 -7 -12
```

***Код:***

```cs
foreach (int a in massiv) {
    if      (a < 0 && a < d) { d = a; }
    else if (a > 0 && a < c) { c = a; }
}
for (int i = 0; i < massiv.Length; i++) {
    if      (massiv[i] == d) { massiv[i] = c; }
    else if (massiv[i] == c) { massiv[i] = d; }
}
```

> Как можно сделать это без цикла `for`?

Comment: Это хоршо, когда у вас есть задача, вам значит есть чем заняться. Но в чем состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: foreach(int a in massiv)
    {
         if (a < 0 && a < d)
         {
               d = a;
      }
         else if (a > 0 && a < c)
             {
                 c = a;
                }           
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < massiv.Length; i++)
            {
                if (massiv[i] == d)
                {
                    massiv[i] = c;
                }
                else if (massiv[i] == c)
                {
                    massiv[i] = d;
                }
            }   вопрос в том что нужно сделать как то без цикла for это

Comment: Перенесите это в вопрос, а не в комментариях пишите :) И у Вас минус перед 12 потерялся

Comment: запихнуть все в List<T> и применить linq по max/min и затем найти их индексы и поменять местами

Comment: @Dude36 и как же с помощью max/min найти ближайшее к 0 положительное число?

Answer (score 7):

Без цикла никак не обойтись. Он может быть спрятан в конструкциях LINQ, но он так или иначе будет присутствовать.

*максимальный по модулю отрицательный элемент* - иначе говоря, это просто минимальный элемент.

Давайте сделаем решение с помощью современных средств C#: ref local и value tuple.

Мы сохраняем не *индексы* элементов, а *ссылки* на них.
Обмен элементов производим лаконично в одно строку.

```
var arr = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, -12, -3, 4, -5, -7, 2 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));

ref int minNeg = ref arr[0];
ref int minPos = ref arr[0];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (minNeg > arr[i])
        minNeg = ref arr[i];

    if (arr[i] >= 0 && minPos > arr[i])
        minPos = ref arr[i];
}

(minNeg, minPos) = (minPos, minNeg);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", arr));
```

Просто захотелось попробовать новые возможности языка.

Comment: обмен ссылками value типов... мсье знает толк, надо плюсовать :)

Comment: Если бы это было фильмом, я бы назвал его "C#: восстание указателей" :)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете заменить цикл на обычное `goto`. Такое:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) ...
```

Превратится в такое:

```
int i = 0;
loopStart:
if (i >= arr.Length) goto loopEnd;
...
i++;
goto loopStart;
loopEnd: ;
```

Но преподы не любят `goto`, поэтому есть и второй способ.

Если задание принципиально требует решить без цикла, замените его искусственно на рекурсию. Пример функции нахождения минимума (возвращает индекс минимального элемента):

```
int minIndex (int[] arr, int i = 1, int minI = 0) =>
    i < arr.Length ? minIndex (arr, i+1, arr[i] < arr[minI] ? i : minI) : minI;
```

Использование:

```
int[] arr  = ...;
int   minI = minIndex (arr);
```

Я, конечно, не собираюсь полностью делать вашу задачу, но надеюсь, что ответ подтолкнет вас в правильном направлении.

Answer (score 2):

```
        int[] arr = { 4, 5, 6, 7, -12, -3, 4, -5, -7, 2 };
        var minPos = Array.IndexOf(arr, arr.Where(n => n > 0).Min());
        var min = Array.IndexOf(arr, arr.Min());
        var temp = arr[minPos];
        arr[minPos] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно найти и таким путем

```
 var arr =new  List<int> { 4, 5, 6, 7, -12, -3, 4, -5, -7, 2 };

            Console.WriteLine($"Maximum {arr.Max()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Minimum {arr.Min()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"IndexMax {arr.IndexOf(arr.Max())}");
            Console.WriteLine($"IndexMin {arr.IndexOf(arr.Min())}");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

поменять местами можно так

```
           var maxIndex = arr.IndexOf(arr.Max());
           var minIndex = arr.IndexOf(arr.Min());
           var buf = arr.Max();
           arr[maxIndex] = arr.Min();
           arr[minIndex] = buf;
```

особо не ругайтесь....

Comment: это не то совсем, что требовалось  вопросе

Comment: tym32167, точно, там еще местами поменять надо, простите щас подправлю )) Спасибо Вам за замечание ))))

Comment: Max тут ни к чему, а минимальный положительный находится так arr.Where(n => n > 0).Min()